# Parsing JSON file with AngualrJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and running some tests, but I'm having the following problem: I'm trying to read a JSON file, parse it into an object and show its properties on the screen. I read that $http parse the JSON text automatically, so I wrote the following code:

```
$http.get("/people").success(
    function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data.people;
    }
);
```

This is my JSON file:

```
{ "people": [
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Cave Jhonson",
        "company": "Aperture Science"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Gustavo Fring",
        "company": "Los Pollos Hermanos"
    }
]
}
```

Which is in my project folder. I'm running a Python server. Finally, I'm trying to show the information with a simple HTML:

```
<p>{{data.people[0].name}}</p>
```

But when I open the page in Firefox the information doesn't show up and I get this error message: " Error: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' "
My JSON is valid, so I can't understand why $http is not parsing it.

Comment: Your json isn't valid. See comma after the "company" line

Comment: Did you check what console.log($data); prints?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong text, my actual JSON doesn't have the commas. Already edited the post

Comment: If you assign data.people to $scope.data, you should call it as **{{data[0].name}}** etc.. alternatively assign data to $scope.date : **$scope.data = data;** and still use {{data.people[0].name}}

Answer (score 0):

this line is inccorrect: `<p>{{data.people[0].name}}</p>`

You already put the code on scope in data so use that

```
<p>{{data[0].name}}</p>
```

Or you can use ng-repeat to show all the records like this

```
<div ng-repeat='item in data'>
   <p>Id: {{item.id}}, Name: {{item.name}}, company: {{item.company}}</p>
<div>
```